# Non-computable=>normal?

Tags: randomness, kolmogorov-complexity, pseudorandomness, pseudorandom-generators

If we have an infinite string of 0's and 1's, such that no finite Turing-machine can output it. What can we say about the string? Must it be normal, ie. must every finite sequence appear infinite times as a subsequence at approriate rates etc?

Comment: What do you mean with pseudo-random? I don't think there is a common property, see the numbers [Omega of Chaitin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chaitin%27s_constant). On the contrary, the number which at position $i$ outputs whether or not the TM $M_i$ halts is not a random number.

Comment: @Gopi Omega is listed as one of the examples of Martin-Löf random (normal) numbers.

Comment: The answers to [this question](http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/q/1263/30) address your own question, and generalizations of it.

Comment: @Golmokorov, this is why I added the last number (I don't know if it has a name, I read somewhere that it was called $\tau$) as a not random number.

Comment: The answer is no. There are uncountable many non-normal numbers but only countable many programs.

Comment: @AaronSterling does this count as a duplicate then ?

Comment: @Golmokorov: Or more explicitly, we can obtain a non-normal non-computable infinite string by e.g. interleaving any non-computable infinite string with the infinite string 000….

Comment: @Suresh: I suppose someone could answer it relating normality to Martin-Lof tests.  I don't consider it a duplicate, but I also don't consider it sufficiently different to answer instead of commenting. :-)  Not very helpful, I know.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, the string need not be normal.  Take any uncomputable sequence and add two 0s between each term; now there are too many 0s for the sequence to be normal but it's still uncomputable.

Comment: Cool, but I still wonder what can be said about the number distribution, if anything?

Comment: You can pad the sequence as much as you like, so certainly you can make an arbitrary pattern as common or as rare as desired.  I can't think of any nontrivial distributional qualities such a sequence would necessarily have.